# MySQL nested INSERT statements

Tags: mysql, nested, sql-insert

Can you nest `INSERT` statements in MySQL?

I have this schema:

```
T1(ids)
T2(id, x, ...)
T3(id, y, ...)
```

What I need to do is copy data from table `T2` to table `T3` while modifying some fields and adding new data to `T3`, then updating the parent table `T1` to reference the new records.

I know we can run a command like this to copy records between tables:

```
INSERT INTO T3 SELECT id+1000, X, 'new', ... FROM T2
```

However I then need to pipe the new records that have been created into `T1`.
Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO T1 SELECT id FROM 
    (INSERT INTO T3 SELECT id+1000, X, 'new', ... FROM T2)
```

Is this possible? My ids are not auto-increment, `T1` is a list of id's of `T2` and `T3` with some additional data per records. `T2` and `T3` are not identical tables.

I just need to copy data from `T3` to `T2` with new id's and then update `T1` to reflect the new records that were created, all in 1 transaction if possible.

Comment: Have you considered [20.3 Using Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html)?

Comment: I have not, I haven't used triggers before so I didn't even think about them. What I ended up doing instead is splitting it into 2 queries. The first one copies and modifies data from T2 to T3. The second ones searches T3 and adds any records for any id that does not exist in table T1. I run both these queries in a transaction. I'm not sure if this is the best method, but it got the job done for now.